# Using state props/ values in Mixins

Tags: vuejs2

I have used VueJS in the past but this new version takes some getting used to. I have a parent component that need to pass data to the child and when the child is finish with the data needs to unset it.

Should I be using State management or just implement event emitters?

Also can you implement a "store" as a mixin? for the parent child components within the scope of the app rather than global? I ask this because I only need state management between the parent and child component(s) in the scope rather than the global application itself